# Cannot change Word.Application options from C# Installer Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, office-addins

I am developing MS-Word Add-In using Visual Studio 2019 (with C#). I am trying to make my add-in change some Word options, like this:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Set numeral to "Hindi"
    Application.Options.ArabicNumeral = WdArabicNumeral.wdNumeralHindi;
}
```

Although it works, it is not efficient because this code will be executed every time the Word application is opened. I need to execute it only once when my add-in is being **installed**, so I tried to create an **Installer Class** and do it like this:

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    Word.Application app_ = new Word.Application();

    // Set numeral to "Hindi"
    app_.Options.ArabicNumeral = WdArabicNumeral.wdNumeralHindi;
}
```

However, the second method doesn't change numeral to "Hindi" .. Any help ?

**Note:** To make sure that the `Install` function gets executed, I tried to divide by zero to make sure it will give runtime error.

Comment: It only sets it for that `Application` instance, which disappears as soon as Word closes. Why do you think the first method is inefficient? It's only a single call at startup

Comment: It is inefficient to set MS-Word option every time you open a file. You just need to do it once in your life. That's why I am trying to do it in the installation step (a little perfectionist)